# How to send "ctrl+c" cmd through on the serial line by the ruby serialport

Tags: ruby, serial-port, ruby-serialport

I send "top" to the device through serailport,then read the top info

After that, I don't known how to stop the "top"!

```
require 'serialport'
port       = 2
args       ={"baud"=>57600, "data_bits"=>8,"stop_bits"=>1,"parity"=>SerialPort::NONE}
serial_obj = SerialPort.new(port, args)
serial_obj.read_timeout=1000
serial_obj.write("top\n")
print serial_obj.read
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the `ETX` character, which is `"\x03"`. You may also be able to use Ruby's "control" escape sequences, such as `"\cc"` or `"\C-c"`, as referenced [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Backslash_Notation), but I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: both of  "serial_obj.write("\C-c\n")"   “serial_obj.write("\cc\n")”  solve my question!

Comment: If these answer your question, you should accept this as the answer.